# Remove array elements that appear more than once

Tags: c#, arrays

`Array.Distinct()` leaves distinct elements. How can I remove all duplicate elements from Array *including* original one?

For example, given this input array:

```
{ Dog, Cat, Mouse, Dog, Dog, Parrot, Mouse, Hound }
```

I'd like to get this output:

```
{ Cat, Parrot, Hound }
```

Comment: I couldn't find answer to this question on Stackoverflow & google, so why so many downvotes?

Comment: You seem to have three answers, so it's probably me, but I don't understand what you mean. You want Dog removed? (I did not downvote btw.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a bit of Linq:

```
var singles = myArray
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Or like this:

```
var singles = myArray
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(g => !g.Skip(1).Any())
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

- The [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.groupby%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method will collect all similar elements together.
- The [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.where%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method will filter out groups that do not meet a certain condition. I've provided two alternatives conditions, but they both do the same thing—they return `true` only if the group contains exactly one element:

  - `g.Count() == 1` counts the number of elements in each group and returns `true` if the result is equal to 1.
  - `!g.Skip(1).Any()` returns `true` if there are no elements after the first. This is actually marginally more efficient than `g.Count() == 1` because it doesn't require enumerating all elements in the group, but it's a bit confusing to some readers, so think twice before introducing this in production code.
- Finally, [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will return all elements from in the result collection. Since there is only one element in each group, you're left with only those elements which are not duplicated.

Comment: Looks nice and it's well explained. Will try this one :)

Comment: @Selman22 OP doesn't want just the distinct elements, but the elements which do not appear more than once in the input array.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
Array.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() == 1).SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: Looks simple enough to do it's job. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using Group by clause you can get the result.

```
var list = new List<string>  { "Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Dog", "Dog", "Parrot", "Mouse", "Hound" };


        //var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b" };
        var q = (from x in list
                 group x by x into g
                 let count = g.Count()
                 where count == 1
                 orderby count descending
                 select g.Key); 
        foreach (var x in q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myList.Where(i => myList.Count(j => j == i) < 2);
```

Note that this relies on the `==` operator being a good enough comparison (though you could replace it with whatever comparison you want). It also isn't very efficient, though I doubt any of the other answers will be either.

This works by restricting the result to elements that do not appear more than once in the source list.

Comment: Whereas this will work, it will take a very long time on larger lists because it has to go through the entire list for every item.

Comment: @JimMischel, Yes it absolutely has that problem. The group by approach is much more efficient, but I didn't come up with a working one in time :)