# C# unique values from list (removing dupes entirely)

Tags: c#, list, linq

How to achieve the following?

Input List: A,A,B,B,B,C,D,E,E,F

Expected Output List: C,D,F

Comment: `.GroupBy()`, then filter the `.Count()`.

Comment: I had a little chuckle that this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Related: [Remove List<T> elements that appear more than once, in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415957/remove-listt-elements-that-appear-more-than-once-in-place)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use group by and take only groups with exactly one element:

```
var input = new string[] {"A","A","B","B","B","C","D","E","E","F"};
var result = input.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() == 1).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/j2vraK